# Why i can't login in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: xubuntu, login

I have used Xubuntu 16.04 fine for months. Today i updated some snapd package, then i restarted the system as required. And now it just won't let me log in. It replies `invalid password`. I tried to switch to lxde, then a tried to log in to another user account (including root) to no avail.

Then i pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> to enter the CLI environment. Tried to log on (as regular user, then as root) and i keep getting the same message:

> System is booting up. See pam_nologin(8).

I found out that pam_nologin means *Prevent non-root users to login*. And yet i can't log in as root! What can i do? Should i reset root password from a Live Ubuntu?

P.S. I'm so upset i'm not even looking for my Live Ubuntu and i'm writing this from Windows :( .

Comment: Try reseting password as described here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: Nope! That didn't help much! When i try to set a new root password i get this annoying reply: *password not changed* and then *Error on manipulating the authentication token*. Sorry if i didn't nail the exact words, my system language is not set to english, but that's the general picture of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error on manipulating the authentication token.

Becuase filesystem mounted as readonly , you have to remount it with write permission.

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Try this. And always google if something you are not getting.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry about my previous comment. It was my bad! @Thanos Apostolou' method worked too, it's just my fault for being cross-eyed and forgot to type a space between remount and /. I was typing very fast like this `remount/` instead of `remount /`.